# Found code to extract text from PDF, but it is not written for Android, can I still add it to my project?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-ndk

I found simple code to extract text from PDF files [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7056/Code-to-extract-plain-text-from-a-PDF-file), and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to add it to my existing app in order to add this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is doable since the code is written in C. It will be complex if you are a beginner as you will have to use [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to interface the `C` code to `Java` using [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)